# Magento-2 Validate input field without form

Tags: magento2, form-validation

How to validate email input field without form? I have tried with below code but not working.

```
<input class="input-text" 
       type="email" 
       data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"   
       id="email" 
       type="text"
       placeholder="Enter email address" name="email"/>
```

Comment: Why would you have an input field without a form?

Comment: Because it is form inside form.  i can't placed form there because we can't nest forms within another form.

Comment: So it is part of a form then? I don't understand.

Comment: I have one text field on product view page i want to send it to my custom module action.Field validation is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code in js to check field validation

$("#email").valid();

It will return true if is a valid field otherwise it will return false.